# Prepare Query for Search Multiple Collections using Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In my application 2 collections are there.

1.profile - Fields are : username,id,city and postalcode

2.material - id,version,descrption and usage

In single collection we use as shown below :

```
 var query = {};
query.username = 'xxxx';
query.city= 'yyyy';
```

Need Multiple Collections Query as shown below data?

Need query for  to pass **username and city in profile** and **descrption in material?**

Comment: How are these two Collections related?  Why do you have to use one query instead of querying them separately?

Comment: In Profile Id is there and material are also id there.So these two are same.@ Carson Moore

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not support joins in the way a relational DB (e.g., MySQL) does.  There are a number of materials available on the subject, principally...

- [Discover Meteor's tutorial on reactive joins](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/)
- [Reactive and Non-Reactive Join with MongoDB](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-6-reactive-and-nonreactive-join-with-mongodb/12)
- [This HackPad about reactive join packages](https://hackpad.com/Meteor-reactive-join-publication-packages-MpSFfsZrMxa)

What these all boil down to is this: It's not native in MongoDB, but with Meteor, you have three options:

- Use a package to do it for you
- De-normalize (include one collection entirely within the other)
- Do it yourself with publication and routing

From your comment:

> In Profile Id is there and material are also id there.So these two are same

it sounds like the `id` fields are what you'd like to join by -- the second option (de-normalize) here is really easy, if you can get away with it.  Rather than having two Collections, have one Collection in the following format:

```
{
  username,
  material: { 
    version,
    description,
    usage
  },
  city,
  postalcode
}
```

and then query like so:

```
Profiles.find({username: 'xxxx', city: 'yyyy', "material.description": "zzzz"});
```

This has obvious tradeoffs in terms of storage efficiency and re-usability (for instance, if your `material` Collection is used elsewhere, you can't really just embed it in the `profile` Collection).  Note that this also works if you have many materials that have the same description.

If you need to keep them separate, you can narrow down the set of fields to look in manually (option 3) -- you can see how I did that on this [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/JbuqhDvbBPhMhS9mS/RelationPackage), but the basic idea is in your publish function, query one Collection first, then use that information to query the other:

```
// Return all profiles with a certain material description -- includes multiple materials.
Meteor.publish('profiles', function(username, city, material) { 
  var materialIds = Materials.find({description: material}).map(function(mat) { return mat._id });

  return Profiles.find({material: {$in: materialIds}, username: username, city: city});
});
```

There are a lot of choices for packages, so I will leave it up to you to find the one most suited to your needs and read the documentation if that's the route you choose.

Comment: @user2344293 what about it doesn't work? I am happy to help out, but I can't do so unless I know more. Do these solutions not fit your use case?  Are you getting errors? Does the MeteorPad example not make sense? What have you tried?

Comment: Exactly i need search like filter for example basically filter query is given based profile fields and one more option is also give search field is material descrption.So dcscrption is not single it may be there duplicates.This time get result like don't check profile but materaila descrption will be check.so can write query for this?@Carson Moore

Comment: @user2344293 All of the above solutions still work in the case where you need to find multiple materials.  You can use MongoDB's `$in` operator as necessary.  I've updated my answer and the MeteorPad to reflect that. But you cannot do this in one query without de-normalizing or adding a relational join package.